# is any python library available to use for AD group policy operations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, active-directory, group-policy, active-directory-group

Is there any python library available to use for AD group policy operations?

I have used ldap3, pyad, and active_directory library, but these libraries do not support group policy operations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any special Python library just for reading Group Policy, but you don't necessarily need one. It can be done with LDAP and reading a file share. However, it's little difficult to put all the pieces together. There is a good walk-through of it [here](https://www.totalnetsolutions.net/2017/09/13/getting-group-policy-information-via-ldap-and-smb-only/).

That link gives the example of finding the Default Domain Policy, but it can be done for any OU.

1. Use LDAP to read the `gPLink` attribute on the root node of the domain (e.g. `LDAP://DC=example,DC=com`). The `gPLink` attribute contains one or more LDAP paths to policy objects. The format of that string is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-gpol/08090b22-bc16-49f4-8e10-f27a8fb16d18) (starting at "gpLink: MUST be a Directory String...")
2. Bind to that LDAP path and read the `gPCFileSysPath`, which is a file share.
3. Access that file share, which contains folders for all the settings of the policy. Eventually you'll find an ini or inf file that contains settings. That page I linked to gives the example of finding the password policy, which is in `MACHINE\Microsoft\Windows NT\SecEdit\GptTmpl.inf`.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 for every LDAP path you found in step 1. Each policy in the list has priority over the previous (the second policy can overwrite settings from the previous).
5. Repeat steps 1-3 for each OU up to the OU you're interested in. So if you want to know the policies that apply to to `OU=Users,OU=London,DC=example,DC=com`, you need to repeat this for:

   1. `DC=example,DC=com`
   2. `OU=London,DC=example,DC=com`
   3. `OU=Users,OU=London,DC=example,DC=com`

In that order.